# qgis2web problem exporting with match project crs

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I am trying to export a map that contains two layers (one is a duplicate of the other, but with different symbology). If I leave the box "Match Project CRS" unchecked, the map exports with no problem. If I check the box, however, I get a blank map - no features and no layers legend. The project is in USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic, EPSG102003. The layers, however are in

> USER:100026 - * Generated CRS (+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5
>   +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs) - Projected.

I've attempted to export the layer (as shapefile) into EPSG102003, but when I reload it, it's still in the user CRS.

I suspect the layer CRS is at the root of the problem, but I can't figure out how to coerce it to save in the CRS I want.

QGIS 3.4.2, qgis2web 3.12.1, exporting as OpenLayers